# Dump Analysis with Source, using Visual Studio 2008 Express?

Tags: visual-studio, dump, crash-dumps, minidump, memory-dump

Is there any way to analyze app-crash minidumps (e.g. created by SetUnhandledExceptionFilter, or minidumpwritedump()) with source, using Visual Studio 2008 Express?

I generally do this at work using "real" versions of VS, but when trying to get it to work on my personal projects (using VS 2008 Express) it tells me "There is no source code available for the current location." and refuses to give me anything other than a disassembly window.  Symbols for the app in question are loaded by the debugger, the "Debug Source Files" property page includes a pointer to the directory in which my source-code lives, but no dice.

Is it even possible to do this via the Express edition of VS 2008?  If so, does anyone have any advice as to what else I could try to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the Express edition can do this. but if you need to do it with a free product, you can use WinDBG instead. WinDBG is part of the [Debugging Tool for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx).

Comment: Yes, but the interface for WinDbg is quite unwieldy.  The project I'm working on is open-source, and I'm hoping to document a quickie guide to minidump analysis so that volunteers can assist with minidump triage.  Not sure WinBg is the right tool for the casual contributor...  =;)